# Does killing Brent Radford fail the Pacifist achievement?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I am doing the side quest "Acquaintances Forgotten", where I have come across an individual named Brent Radford who is severely injured after being beaten by some guys who're after information on you.

As I go through the conversation options he asks me to give him a lethal dose of morphine to put him out of his misery, and upon doing so he is marked with the Skull when I target him, indicating he is dead.

Does this invalid the "Pacifist" achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not, while you have technically 'killed' him this will not count against the Pacifist achievement.

There are only three actions that will not result in failing this achievement:

- Killing bosses
- Killing ENEMY robots (killing friendly robots will fail the achievement)
- Killing Brent Radford with a morphine overdose

Provided you have not killed any human or friendly robot throughout the course of your play-through you will not fail the Pacifist achievement.

Comment: You can also kill the test subject girl in the undersea lab in Missing Link. If you play DC version this also does not count against Pacifist.